# Zend dynamically set layout

Tags: javascript, php, html, zend-framework

I'm very new in Php and Zend. I have a problem of setting layout dynamically.

I have a controller and an action that controls a view. The view have 2 tabs called "tabA" and "tabB". I want to change the layout by using

```
$this->layout()->setLayout('other-layout');
```

when I switch to "tabA" but keep the default layout when switching to "tabB". How can I do that?

Comment: you cant change layout in  view file based on tabs...tabs are just 'ul' that is controlled by javascript witch...layout changing is a server side issue...tabs are changed in client side.i recommend using ajax..

Comment: can you give me more details on how to use ajax in this case?

Comment: you want to change  whole page layout or you want to change layout of a specific div?

Comment: the whole page. I will capture the event when switching to the tab, then using ajax to call to Php to change the layout, rite? Can you tell me how to capture the event when a tab selected and how to use ajax to change the layout?

Comment: but remember :loading whole page with ajax in NOT A GOOD IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant change layout in view file based on tabs...tabs are just 'ul' that is controlled by javascript...layout changing is a server side issue...tabs are changed in client side.i recommend using ajax.
if you want to change the whole page layout by ajax(not a good way) you can do this:
suppose the tab that should change the page layout has id="tab1"..
so:

```
<script>
 $('#tab1').on('click' ,function(){
  $(document).load('/sample_controller/sample_action');
})
</script>
```

the sample_action is exactly like the action  that you are in right now.but in its last line you have have something like this:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('other-layout');
```

Comment: a tab can be switched to through url, for example http://example.com#tab1. How can I trigger the event when a tab is selected by this way?

Comment: @Nhat Nam:first of all,you should ask 1 question  then if you got your answer ask another one by  creating a new question..

Comment: so..did my answer helped you?